# Upsert in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, upsert

Is there a built-in way to make upsert (insert if not exists) in Mongoid? Or should I check if an item exists first and only after that make insert/update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in upsert method in Mongoid already

> Performs a MongoDB upsert on the document. If the document exists in the database, it will get overwritten with the current attributes of the document in memory. If the document does not exist in the database, it will be inserted. Note that this only runs the {before|after|around}_upsert callbacks.

Taken from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/7.3/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/

Comment: How to do it for has_many. Suppose User has many Books, I want the books of user to get updated, added, modified ? User.first.upsert(:books_attributes => ?) ???

Comment: @user1735921it's been a while since I've used MongoDB, but a quick look at the current docs shows - https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-bulk-operations/#update-many

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
person = Person.new(
   first_name: "Heinrich",
   last_name: "Heine"
)
person.upsert
```

Source:
https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html